# Getting an error when I am trying to make a connection with my database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6

I have created my database on SQL Server Management Studio, and trying to add an Entity Data Model (ADO.NET) to my project, the connection was testable but when I hit "OK" button this error established:

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

**Could not find any resources appropriate for the specified culture or the neutral culture. Make sure "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.SqlViewSupport.xml" was correctly embedded or linked into assembly "Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer" at compile time, or that all the satellite assemblies required are loadable and fully signed.**

Answer (score 1):

> [Workaround] As temporary workaround you can use provider assembly
> from previous studio version. Place attached file (from studio version
> 16.10.4) to …\Common7\IDE folder of your installation.

[Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.zip](https://aka.ms/dc/file?name=Bca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050_Microsoft.VisualStudio.Data.Providers.SqlServer.zip&tid=ca7bb94432284501a611a5e99c16736e637648143331623050)

[Developer Community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Could-not-find-any-resources-appropriate/1505966#T-N1506125)